# I get "permission denied" when docker run the npm run serve command

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, vuejs3

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install @vue/cli@5.0.8 -g

RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

I use **node alpine** well and I already tried `chmod 777` or `npm config set unsafe-perm true` but nothing works...

and this is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  frontend:
    build: ./services/frontend
    volumes:
      - './services/frontend:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

here is the error I get when I run `sudo docker compose up --build`:

```
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | 
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | > frontend@0.1.0 serve
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | > vue-cli-service serve
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | 
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  |  INFO  Starting development server...
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error11:24:09 AM
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | 
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  |  error  in ./node_modules/events/events.js
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | 
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | Syntax Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/node_modules/.cache'
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | 
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | 
ERROR in ./node_modules/events/events.js
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/node_modules/.cache'
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  |  @ ./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js 1:19-36
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  |  @ ./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js 50:18-38
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | 
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=auto%3A&username=&password=&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=0&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&progress=true&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/node_modules/.cache'
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | 
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | ERROR in ./src/main.js
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/node_modules/.cache'
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | 
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | ERROR in [eslint] EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/node_modules/.cache/eslint'
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | 
fastapi-vue-frontend-1  | webpack compiled with 4 errors
```

what I don't understand is that it doesn't affect all the files but only the .cache folder (is it because of the hidden folder??)

Comment: The `volumes:` block is basically causing everything in your Dockerfile to be ignored, and depending on the host-system Docker setup it could potentially cause this permission error.  If you delete the `volumes:` block, does it work better?

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer it allowed me to solve my problem by removing the line: - '/app/node_modules' in volumes

Comment: But doesn't that prevent my app from accessing it?

Comment: Remove the _entire_ `volumes:` block.  The code is built into your image.

Comment: I have an error when I remove the entire `volumes:` --> `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/main.js' in '/app'`

Comment: ...are you missing the `COPY ./ ./` line that would copy the application into your image?

Comment: @DavidMaze Actually it's not really built. He uses the `npm run serve` command.
Maybe he just wants hot reload feature whlie developing.

Comment: IME plain Node without Docker works much better for this use case; you actively do not want your application runtime to be isolated from the host filesystem.